# dynamic linking error of libraries in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, linker, cassandra-3.0, datastax-c++-driver

I am able to link the dynamic library but getting errors while executing. Can anyone please explain why? I am new to dynamic libraries and Cassandra.

Moreover, can anyone please point out some pros and cons of using a C driver in Cassandra?

Pasting the output here:

```
stark@stark-MS-7788:~/cpp-driver/examples/basic$ ll total 24040 drwxrwxr-x  stark stark    4096 Oct 23 12:27 ./ drwxrwxr-x 23 stark stark    4096 Oct 23 09:58 ../
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stark stark   18968 Oct 23 11:46 a.out*
-rw-rw-r--  1 stark stark    6283 Oct 23 11:31 basic.c
-rw-rw-r--  1 stark stark    8672 Oct 23 12:17 basic.o
-rw-rw-r--  1 stark stark  281187 Oct 23 11:31 cassandra.h
-rw-rw-r--  1 stark stark     537 Oct 23 09:58 CMakeLists.txt
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stark stark   18968 Oct 23 12:27 demo*
-rw-rw-r--  1 stark stark       6 Oct 23 09:58 .gitignore
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stark stark 8084160 Oct 23 12:27 libcassandra.so*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stark stark 8084160 Oct 23 12:27 libcassandra.so.2*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 stark stark 8084160 Oct 23 12:27 libcassandra.so.2.7.1* 
stark@stark-MS-7788:~/cpp-driver/examples/basic$ gcc -o demo basic.o libcassandra.so.2.7.1
stark@stark-MS-7788:~/cpp-driver/examples/basic$ ./demo ./demo: error while loading shared libraries: libcassandra.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[The output image for the both cases is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh7bO.png)

Comment: Instead of linking as `gcc -o demo basic.o libcassandra.so.2.7.1` try `gcc -o demo basic.o -lcassandra`

Comment: thanks ajay.. it worked... can you just elaborate the difference? It will be of very useful.

Comment: To answer that question I will ask you to compile the program with both the ways and on both the binaries run `ldd demo`. In the working case it will show where it is loading the `.so` from.

Comment: I checked both the outputs and both are same.. not even small difference except where the address space it is loaded(which will be random anyways).

Comment: Can you paste the output as an edit to your question so I can look at it?

Comment: yes, did both the cases and posted the output as an edit.

Comment: Hi ajay, can you please go through the screenshot added at the ending of the post and give me some info...